# Como definir margens no jsPDF?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jspdf

Estou montando um formulário e preciso extraí-lo como .pdf e pra isso estou usando jsPDF. O problema é que não consigo definir uma margem direita e os dados colocados na textarea do formulário acabam sendo cortados quando o pdf é gerado.

Honestamente não sei mexer muito bem com JavaScript, então talvez meu código não seja o mais inteligente possível, mas está funcionando.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        var system = $.trim($("#sistema").val());
        if(system != ""){
            var doc = new jsPDF("p", "pt", "a4");

            doc.setFontType("bold").setFontSize(18).text("FORMULÁRIO",150,70);
            doc.setFontType("bold").setFontSize(14).text("SISTEMA:",50,100);
            doc.setFontType("normal").setFontSize(12).text(system,50,125);
        }
```

```
                    <tr>
                        <td><label><strong>Sistema:</strong></label></td>
                        <td><textarea id="sistema" rows="1" cols="22" placeholder="Insira o nome do sistema." required></textarea></td>
                    </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para criar line breaks é preciso usar a função splitTextToSize().

```
var texto = doc.splitTextToSize(system, 570)
doc.setFontType("normal").setFontSize(12).text(texto,50,125);
```